# Is there any correlation between low-quality questions and the devices they originated from?

Tags: discussion, mobile-app

I cannot see myself using my phone to ask a question on any Stack Exchange networks. The comfort and experience simply doesn't compare with the non-mobile web version.

I know that I would probably have less examples and/or external references if I ever had to use my phone to post a question.

I appreciate this is coming from my own little insignificant perspective but I was wondering whether this may actually be a thing? **Does the mobile app encourage or make people be less thorough when asking questions?**

Are there any evidences to suggest that mobile devices generate more low-quality questions than any other platforms on average?

[Possibly related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247472/414537)

Comment: Great question!  I know I've long been frustrated by posts that read like text message, "can u hlp me? :-)", etc..